# Mix strings with numbers on Eval Expression of Breakpoints on Delphi

Tags: delphi, conditional-statements, logging, breakpoints

I'm using Delphi XE2. 
And I would like to able to log data using the Delphi Breakpoints.
Ex: Format('%s:%d', [Name, Id])

When I try this, it doesn't recognizes Format.
I didn't found any details on Delphi Help on how to do it.

The big benefit of using Delphi Breakpoints without break option, is that I don't need to recompile to log more data, over the traditional code logging.
Since, this data its very temporary, and I'm using only to locate a bug, and once its found its no longer needed. 
This real-time facility its very helpful, if allows me to log more than one variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
Name + ':' + IntToStr(Id)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is there any place where I can find a list of which functions work, and which don't?

Comment: Normally all functions, which does not have open array params, which are not inlined, or eliminated by linker.